# jquery mobile multi-page first page init

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm using multi-page template structure so that essentially means that user can start on any ONE page that is inside the template.

I want to perform some action just once no matter which page user starts (and then when user navigates between the pages the action MUST NOT be repeated).

```
$('#my1page').on('pageinit', function(event){
  // blahblah setup websocket
});
$('#my_other_page').on('pageinit', function(event){
// blahblah setup websocket
});
$('#and_heres_another_page').on('pageinit', function(event){
// blahblah setup websocket
});
```

So I want to group all above together to be just

```
$('#FIRST-WHATEVER-PAGE-USER-NAVIGATES-INTO').on('pageinit', function(event){
// blahblah setup websocket
});
```

Under normal circumstances I would use document.ready() but this is a very big NO-NO for jquerymobile.

Comment: try `$(document).on('pageinit', function () { code }).off('pageinit');`

Comment: @Omar does not work at all. The event is not fired even once.

Comment: replace `document` with `[data-role=page]`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('pageinit', function () 
{ 
   //do something here 
});
```

this should do the job for all pages in the document, also if you add some more later dynamically.

EDIT: take a look at the syntax of the .on() function in jquery

[click me](http://www.elijahmanor.com/2012/02/differences-between-jquery-bind-vs-live.html)

Comment: Well this one actually is being fired on every pageinit. But I've modified slightly to add variable at the begining like:
`var wasUsed = false;
$(document).on('pageinit', function ()
{ 
   if (wasUsed) return ;
   wasUsed = true;
});`

Comment: of course, thought the question targeted only the $(document) aspect ;)